# understanding and/or troubleshooting XMLHttpRequest - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I am not an experienced web developer by any means, so I apologize if this is very basic / newb question.  I did try researching this error message, but my skillset lies in different areas, so I was hoping someone could maybe give me a pointer.

We have a SWG (secure web gateway) inline that may or may not be causing this, since access works in IE, but not in Chrome - and the SWG just went inline recently - so am trying to find some root cause for this error.

here is the error message that I pull out of Chrome's Console debugger:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load .... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.*

the "..." shows a URL that referes to a googlevideo.com link, but I am trying to view a video on youtube.com - any video for that matter.

seems that this is an XSS defense mechanism, but I dont see any blocks in the SWG, nor are some of the next-gen features even enabled

Chrome version - Version 51.0.2704.63 m (64-bit)
IE version - 11.0.9600.18314

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`--disable-web-security` now requires the use of the `--user-data-dir` flag.

Start-up your chrome with below command on windows:

chrome.exe `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

**OR**

1. Open **Properties** window of **Google Chrome short cut icon available on desktop**.
2. Go to the **Shortcut tab**
3. Specify the following flag **at the end of path**

"C:...\Application\chrome.exe" `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

**Just specifying `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir` (without a value) worked for me.**

**If this didn't work** for you then try specifying some folder path:

```
--user-data-dir=$HOME/path/to/some/folder
```